# Vaadin 7 ExcelExport exported file is not correctly formatted.

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have my own class extends ExcelExport. I used it in my code as follows:-

```
    ExcelExportFA2 excelExport = new ExcelExportFA2(exportTable);
    excelExport.excludeCollapsedColumns();
    excelExport.setUseTableFormatPropertyValue(true);
    excelExport.setDisplayTotals(true);
    excelExport.setReportTitle(null);
    excelExport.setDateDataFormat(SalkkuTM.getI18N("dateFormat"));

    try{
        excelExport.setExportFileName( getCaption().replace(" ", "_") + "_" +
                new ExcelExportUtil().getDateString(new Date()) + ".xls" );
    }catch(Exception e){
        excelExport.setExportFileName(SalkkuTM.getI18N("ExportFile.caption"));
    }

    excelExport.export();
```

It exports the file. But the file total row is not correctly formatted. It is left aligned. How can I make it right aligned? Please check the exported [file HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YZk8hvyWul-RGHVVu0l3gJsiH-fSL-UW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExcelExport class looks like the best bet is to override the ExcelExport.defaultTotalsDoubleCellStyle() method and reconfigure the CellStyle.alignment property accordingly. Also the exported table column needs to set alignment accordingly. This way I could solve my problem.